# How to get a copy of all uploaded images from a Plone site

Tags: image, download, plone

I am working on a plone site with version 4. I want to have a copy of all the uploaded images. What is the way to get it? I couldn't get appropriate documentation for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with the Linux command line and want something quick and dirty to get ALL images locally, you can add a script (Python) via the zmi into the portal_skins/custom folder on the Plone site, with the following code:

```
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName

base = 'http://example.com/'
pc = getToolByName(context, 'portal_catalog')
query = {'portal_type': 'Image'}
brains = pc(query)
for brain in brains:
    path = brain.getObject().absolute_url()[len(base):]
    dire = '/'.join(path.split('/')[:-1])
    print "mkdir -p '%s';wget %s%s -O '%s'" % (dire, base, path, path)
return printed
```

(Replace example.com with your site domain name)

Call the script 'image_links'.

Then go to to http://example.com/image_links

You should see a whole bunch of bash shell script commands on the web page. Copy and paste those into a terminal, and your machine should download the images.

Alternatively, put those commands into a shell script and download them all at once.

This produces a directory structure with all images on the site.

I used something similar a few weeks ago to download 3500 images from a client site. Took an hour or 2, but without involvement from me.

Keep in mind that this is quick and dirty: Images get the Plone object name, so might not have the correct extension, etc. YMMV.

Comment: It's working. but its not giving images which are uploaded through a form in Plone. I also want images in web-profiles.

Comment: That's going to take a bit of debugging to figure out. If you can give me a bit more info about how those images are stored, that would help.

Comment: Assuming you have shell access, you can also just create a copy of the entire blobstorage tree and use a tool like `file` to find out which of the blobs are images, though you lose the original name and location. (And this also doesn't catch things like the image embedded into news items, which are not proper image blobs.)

Comment: @Johan: The url for images stored via user profile form is of the format http://siteurl/staff/username/image. staff is a foldername and username is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

A simple (but manual) way is to connect to your Plone site using a webdav client and authenticating using Plone credentials.

In this way you can move inside Plone folders and drag & drop images from remove site to your local machine.

Comment: It sounds exactly what I want. But how to use connect to server option? Its not working. I checked using 'cadaver' for webdav server enabling. Can you provide step by step how to?

Comment: I have experiences with clients like Cyberduck or BitKinex. It's quite easy, you just need to play with connection options, and (if you are using a non root admin user) connect directly to the Plone site (http://yourhost/ploneid).

Also: try to connect directly to the Zope port, skipping any middlewave web server or balancer (so: http://yourhost:port/ploneid).